# Draw an image as a waveform?

Tags: audio, wav, waveform, oscilloscope

I want to export a series of images (a movie) and draw as a waveform, like how:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M9xMuPWAZW8&feature=youtu.be&t=328 did

http://oscilloscopemusic.com/ offers a program for loading 3D `.obj` files but I am currently working in 2D.

I tried opening a .WAV downloaded from http://www.wavtones.com/functiongenerator.php in vim and my terminal program crashed.

I tried `.cat Downloads/wavTones.com.unregistred.sin_1000Hz_-6dBFS_3s.wav | pbcopy` and pasting into a text editor which showed `RIFFæ`.

What is an algorithm for converting a series of images into a .wav? Ideally I'd like to make many images and string them together to make a movie like Oscilloscope Music does.

The Aphex Twin is using more than 2 colors and I'm not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oscilloscope music and the aphex twin thing are very different. 
basically:

Oscilloscope Music: 
This is an XY-Plot, also called Parametric Plot or 2D Plot. 
Visual Side: The idea here is that you have one point (x/y) and you move that dot around (x and y change with t) so quickly that it appears as a line. 
Acoustic Side: You separate the dot into the two axes. The movement of the x coordinate becomes the audio signal of the left channel, the movement of the y coordinate becomes the audio signal of the right channel.

Aphex Twin Spectrogram Trick:
A spectrogram displays how strong which frequency appears. Ie. the audio signal is dissembled into a weighted sum of sin waves of different frequencies. The weight (how much of which frequency) is the color, the y coordinate is the pitch (how high that sin wave is), the x coordinate is the time.

I hope this helps clear things up.